# Combobox in PDF populated with Javascript keeps resetting to zero

Tags: javascript, pdf, combobox, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to put a combobox (named "Additional Users") on a PDF form that populates with values from an array. According to [this help page](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.752.html), it looks like you can use a 2D array to store the keys and values for the combobox.

I've placed the below code on the combobox as a custom calculation script. It will populate the combobox, but once you select an option and click away from it, the value resets to the first option, which in this case is 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
var dropdown = this.getField("Additional Users");
dropdown.setItems([ ["0", 0], ["5", 5], ["10", 10], ["15", 15] ]);
```

Comment: Where exactly are you putting the code? If you just want to populate the list when the document opens, you should put it at the document level or in page level action. If it's in the field, every action on that field will repopulate the list.

Comment: Okay, I moved it off the combobox and now it works. Thank you!